# Leaflet package in R: why are the labels misplaced when plotting them with noHide=T?

Tags: r, geolocation, leaflet, visualization

I am trying to plot gas stations in Spain, and I would like the plot to show the names or brand names of each station. So far I have struggled a little bit with this, but I finally got my way around it:

```
pal2<- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,"RdBu"))(diff(range(b$Price.Gas)))
myMap<- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lat=lati, lng=long, fillColor = pal2,
                   label=as.character(rotulo),labelOptions = lapply(1:length(rotulo), function(x) {
                     labelOptions(opacity=0.9,noHide = T)
                   }),
                   clusterOptions=markerClusterOptions())
```

But as you can see from the picture below, some labels are way off from where they're supposed to be.

[image]

Why does this happen? Also, and this is another issue, when I try to color the circle markers with fillColor=pal2, nothing happens, they all remain the same...

Comment: Can you provide some example data we can use to reproduce the image above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... after playing with it for a while, I realised that it's not that it doesn't work.

What actually happens is:

1. When you zoom in on a spot on the map, the circles appear, but the label is misplaced to where the circles used to lay before we zoomed in
2. If one moves the map with the pointer (drag and drop), leaving those points out of the window view ("drop" with the pointer), and then moves the map back to where those points were... tadaaa! The labels are where they should be!

I guess it is due to the fact that this is a large leaflet map and that rendering must be heavy for the computer... nonetheless I will post the issue on the Leaflet github page. Thanks to anyone that read the question and took time to think about it, hope my answer helps someone else!